# Angular applications with aws amplify console - routing

Tags: angular, url-routing, aws-amplify

I am having trouble understanding Rewrite and Redirect rules with Angular and AWS Amplify Console.

In my angular application I have routes smiliar to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'frontpage', redirectTo: '/somepath/frontpage', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'somepath', component: SecureComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/frontpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'frontpage', component: ForsideComponent }
  ]}
];
```

Using local server (ng serve / localhost) everything works fine.

But when my application is deployed through the Amplify console the only path that works is `somedomain.amplifyapp.com/` which then redirects to `somedomain.amplifyapp.com/login` (as it should). But entering `somedomain.amplifyapp.com/login`, `somedomain.amplifyapp.com/somepath/frontpage` or following links directly gives me a xml access denied page.

The behaviour above is with this rewrite and redirect rule:

```
[
    {
        "source": "**",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Anyone know how to set up the rewrite and redirect rules to work with the Angular Router?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer in the docs. Leaves an answer if anybody else is wondering.

As explained in the aws docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html
Under "Redirects for Single Page Web Apps (SPA)"

We can add the following rule (with regular expression):

```
[
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this redirect doesn't help :( any other ideas?